# Badges for someone else's question

Tags: bug, badges

I just got the badge "Scholar" for asking a question and accepting an answer.
The special part about that is, that the linked question isn't even my question.

Here is a screenshot of the badge in my user tab with the link to the question:
[image: Screenshot new question]

And here is a screenshot of the linked question written by Danalog:

[image: Screenshot of the question]

What causes this bug and has anyone else experienced it?

**Edit: additional information**

- I had one post beeing migrated to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com a few days before noticing the badge

Comment: That is strange! Sounds like a bug for sure. I don't think I've seen this one before.